# Get root and all successors from parent child table on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, parent-child

I'm using ms sql server.
I have a simple table with a parent child relationship, like
Parent, Child

Now I need a query which delivers every Element with itself, all its successors and successors of them an so on.
Example

```
Parent Child
------ -----
A      A1
A1     A11
A      A2
A2     A21
A21    A211
```

Now the result should look like:

```
Root   Successor
------ ---------
A      A
A      A1
A      A11
A      A2
A      A21
A      A211
A1     A1
A1     A11
A11    A11
A2     A2
A2     A21
A2     A211
A21    A21
A21    A211
A211   A211
```

Any idea to do it recursivly on MS SQL Server with a sql query?

I searched for the internet and found some solutions, but not for my problem. I never got a list with the root and all its successor, only parent child for one level.

Comment: What you need in SQL Server is "Recursive CTE". Google it, plenty of examples on similar problems both here on SO and on the web.

Comment: An mistake by me! Sorry, it has to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH CTE_AllRoots AS 
(
    SELECT Parent as Root FROM Table1
    UNION 
    SELECT Child FROM Table1
)
, RCTE AS 
(
    SELECT Root, Root AS Successor FROM CTE_AllRoots
    UNION ALL
    SELECT r.Root, t.Child
    FROM RCTE r
    INNER JOIN Table1 t ON t.Parent = r.Successor
)
SELECT * 
FROM RCTE
ORDER BY Root, Successor
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KdYd_OI8)

Answer (score 0):

We could also use `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT
y1.parent AS Root, y2.child AS Successor
FROM 
yourtable AS y1 
CROSS JOIN 
yourtable AS y2
WHERE y2.child LIKE y1.parent + '%'
UNION
SELECT parent, parent FROM yourtable
UNION
SELECT child, child FROM yourtable
ORDER BY Root, Successor;
```

Note: This could get slow in case your table has a very high amount of rows due to the `LIKE` condition in the `WHERE` clause.

I think using the `CTE` approach should be prefered here, I just wanted to show you another option.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/VqOvyaoT)